# Generate Downloadable Link in Nextcloud

Tags: nextcloud

I need to generate a downloadable (direct) link in nextcloud within Javascript.

After reading [Direct Download](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/OCS/ocs-api-overview.html#direct-download), my approach was:

```
const url = window.OC.linkToRemote('ocs/v2.php/apps/dav/api/v1/direct');
fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: 'fileId=3'})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

I still get a successful page (code 200), but the body states:

```
Error
    App not installed:
```

Sadly I can't find anything in logs.

How can I create a direct downloadable link by using javascript in Nextcloud?